# (EXCEL) Count if Product number has Asset tag in non-table database

Tags: excel

So I have an inventory spreadsheet, based on deployed inventory and what inventory is at what desk, organized by desk number. I would like to have a count of whether or not the desk has an asset tag associated with the product within the worksheet.

It looks roughly like this, but with more information.

```
Item|ProductNum|Desk|AssetTag|SerialNum

Phone|QV99|1001|4031|123456

Computer|AA22|1001|2011|333999

Monitor1|Ect|1001|ect|ect

Monitor2|Ect|1001|ect|ect

Blankrow|Blankrow|blankrow|blankrow

Phone|QV99|1002|4032|123457

Computer|AA22|1002|2012|333998

Monitor1|C212|1002|ect|ect

Monitor2|C212|1002|ect|ect

Blankrow|Blankrow|blankrow|blankrow

Phone|QV99|1003|blank|blank

Computer|AA22|1003|blank|blank

Monitor1|C212|1003|blank|blank

Monitor2|C212|1003|blank|blank

Blankrow|Blankrow|blankrow|blankrow
```

So logically I'd want to Countif or Countifs, but I'm pretty sure that isn't actually what I need(because excel logic), and I can't figure out how to get it to count the cells if two criteria are met, and similar cells in the same column of one of the ifs also contain similar data.

So like, I need a formula to look for the product number, if it's in that cell, look a to column with the asset tags, and if it's not blank, count it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "because excel logic", but... by my logic `countifs()` seems like the right way to go here.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get CountIfs to look at one cell, then look at a different cell on the same row, but not the same column and determine if it's empty or not. Because the different objects all have similar asset tags.